# How can I track the designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, designer

I have a form in VS2010.
There's a panel in a base class that is set to visible **false** (Through a custom property).
When I open it in the designer the panel shows, though when i look at the property, it's false.
But when I run the program it's invisible and everything's fine.
If I go to the properties and set to true, and then false again, it will disappear.

How can I track what the designer's doing ?  Or what can cause this to happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems in [this link](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html) that

> Another issue of the DesignMode property is that it doesn't work inside the constructor of a UserControl or Form!

Perhaps you'll find other interesting tidbits in there as well?

Comment: It's not an issue with identifying DesignMode. It should just work. I don't see any reason why it will be different in runtime.

Comment: You say that your property seems to behave as if not set -> The first time <-. Doesn't that ring "constructor !!" to you?

Comment: The property is set to false by default in the control's base class.

Comment: I'll be back at work on Sunday I'll play around with it a bit. I've tried moving the default declaration. Tried: variable declaration (C#'s default is false anyway), constructor, InitializeComponent()

Comment: Actually a question in the end of the article helped me :)